# Azure Cognitive Services Content Monitor cannot detect UK phone numbers

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

As explained in the title, I want to use the Azure Cognitive Services Content Moderator API to detect PII, however the service won't detect UK phone numbers.

For example the following are all valid UK phone number formats and are not detected as PII:

- 01xx xxx xxxx
- 020 xxxx xxxx
- +44 xx xxx xxxx
- xxx xxxx
- 077xx xxxxxx

NB **x** is any number [0-9], spaces are for readability only can be omitted completely, or appear in arbitrary places

To replicate, navigate to the Content Moderator console and enter phone numbers in the above format, and they will not be detected. The US phone number provided as an example is detected, however.

Is there a localisation setting I am missing, or is this only set up for US phone numbers?

Comment: Nick, I am from the Content Moderator team. The support for detecting UK numbers is in fact in testing and should be deployed by next week. I will update this thread when that happens. Out of your examples listed, xxx xxxx will not be detected, but others will be. Also, the 020 xxx xxxx is incorrect. 020 xxxx xxxx is the correct format and will be detected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick,

We have just deployed an update to the Content Moderator service. It now detects possible UK phone numbers.

Please see the updated [API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/content-moderator/text-moderation-api) and the [.NET quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/content-moderator/text-moderation-quickstart-dotnet) for the sample input and the JSON response.

Also refer to my previous comment on your examples.

Let us know if this meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a small test to see whether this was possible and apparently it's not.

I [created a custom term list](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/57cf755e3f9b070c105bd2c2/operations/57cf755e3f9b070868a1f67f) with a random UK phone number in it. Then I updated the [list's search index](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/57cf755e3f9b070c105bd2c2/operations/57cf755e3f9b070868a1f684), and then I tried to [match](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/57cf753a3f9b070c105bd2c1/operations/57cf753a3f9b070868a1f66f) a UK phone number against that list.

The operation didn't return the original phone as a match.

**However**, I know that the matching is fuzzy, so it might be worth trying adding more phone numbers to the custom list. Since adding N terms to the list requires N API calls, I figured it was not worth the cost.

You can see the test code [here](https://github.com/joshbalfour/node-cognitive-services/blob/master/test/vision/contentModeratorTest.js#L595).

Comment: I've raised an improvement request with the Azure team and they say they have passed this on to the relevant team. Your solution would work, but as you say there would be a significant cost in populating and maintaining a custom list. I just want to return strings that "look like" UK phone numbers. The fact that this is already done for US phone numbers means that the technology is already there, and it seems pointless reinventing the wheel.